# How to calculate the boundary points and center of a circle fitting inside a crescent?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Given are two intersecting circles $A, B$ with radius $r_A > r_B$ and center $M_A, M_B$. A third circle $C$ with radius $r_C$ and center $M_C$ fits in the non intersecting part of circle $B$ and touches the two circles $A, B$ at the points $P_{CA}, P_{CB}$. What are the results for $M_C, P_{CA}, P_{CB}$ for given $A, B, r_C$?

[image]

Not part of question, only thougts on solving:
Does the path for $M_C$ describe a part of an ellipse? This could be the first step to the solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

We may assume $M_A=(0,0)$, $M_B=(d,0)$, $\>d>0$, and let $a$, $b$ be the radii of the two circles $A$ and $B$.  Let $M_C=(u,v)$ be the center of a touching circle and $r$ its radius. The conditions $|M_C M_A|= a+r$ and $|M_C M_B|=b-r$ enforce
$$u^2+v^2=(a+r)^2,\qquad(u-d)^2+v^2=(b-r)^2\ .\tag{1}$$
Subtracting the second of these equations from the first gives
$$2ud -d^2=(a+b)(a-b+2r)\ .$$
This determines $u=u(r)$, and the first equation $(1)$ then gives $v=\pm v(r)$, whereby $0\leq r\leq{1\over2}(d+b-a)$, by inspection of the figure.

Comment: Is $(u−d)^2+v^2$ correct or should it be $u^2+(v-d)^2$?

Comment: There was a typo in the definition of $M_B$. Sorry.

Comment: I come across for this special case $M_C = (u,v)$ with:
$$u=\frac{((a+b)(a-b+2r))}{2d}+\frac{d}{2}\ .\tag{2}$$
$$v=\pm\sqrt{(a+r)^2-u^2}\ .\tag{3}$$
For a generic solution there has to be done some work: a translation of all generic objects from $M_A$ to the origin and afterwards a rotation to fit $M_B$. After the calculation of $M_C$ this has to be done backwards to get the generic $M_C$.
$$$$Finding the touching points is now trivial as it is only a calculation of the intersections of the lines $|M_A M_C|$ with circle $A$ and $|M_B M_C|$ with circle $B$

Answer (score 0):

I have put a Geogebra sheet at https://www.geogebra.org/m/qnFkgnev.  I am going to write the 4 equations needed to solve for the smallest circle. A convention that I am using: If I have fixed the value of a point, then it is addressed as $(x(P),y(P))$, whereas, if I have the point as an unknown, it is addressed as $(P_x,P_y)$  In the Geogebra sheet, you can move point C about but the browser is slow.  So, click, hold down and move cursor to a new spot on the circle, release. Wait a few seconds and hopefully all will recalculate/redraw. My 4 unknowns are $D_x,D_y,E_x,E_y$

1. Unknown point D, is on the line between B & C. m is the slope of that line. $$m=\left(\frac{y(B)-y(C)}{x(B)-x(C)}\right)$$ The equation: $$D_y=y(C)+m(D_x-x(C))$$
2. The radius of the small circle is the same between C & D and between E & D. $$|C-D|=|E-D|$$
3. Point E has to lie on circle A.  $$E_x^2+E_y^2-3E_x-3E_y=4.5$$ (I think this circle is hard coded in the geogebra sheet, hence the numerical values shown in this equation.)
4. Point D must lie on a line from A through E. $$m_1=\left(\frac{E_y-y(A)}{E_x-x(A)}\right)$$ and the equation: $$D_y=E_y+m_1(D_x-E_x)$$

Once these were solved (by Geogebra CAS), I could move the fixed point C about and a new point D was generated.  I saved these using $SetValue(D_n,D)$.  Next I chose 3 of the D values and put a circle through them.  Surprise (or not), that circle does not quite go through all of the D values.  i.e. the locus of points in question do not quite make the arc of a circle. Is it an ellipse?  Maybe, but that certainly isn't proven yet.

Answer (score 0):

From
$$
M_AM_C=r_A+r_C
\quad\text{and}\quad
M_BM_C=r_B-r_C
$$
we get
$$
M_AM_C+M_BM_C=r_A+r_B=\text{constant},
$$
hence point $M_C$ belongs to the ellipse with foci $M_A$, $M_B$ and semi-axes
$$
a={r_A+r_B\over2},
\quad
b=\sqrt{a^2-c^2},
\quad\text{with}\quad
c=M_AM_B.
$$
The polar equation for $r(\theta)=M_AM_C=r_A+r_C$ is
$$
r(\theta)={b^2\over a-c\cos\theta},
$$
where $\theta=\angle M_BM_AM_C$.
Hence:
$$
\cos\theta={a\over c}-{b^2/c\over r_A+r_C}.
$$
From that it is easy to get the coordinates of $M_C$, $P_{CA}$, $P_{CB}$. Setting:
$$
\hat u={M_B-M_A\over M_AM_B},\quad
\hat v=(-u_y,u_x)
$$
we have:
$$
M_C=M_A+\hat u\,(r_A+r_C)\cos\theta +\hat v\,(r_A+r_C)\sin\theta 
$$
and
$$
P_{AC}=M_A+{r_A\over r_A+r_C}(M_C-M_A),
\quad
P_{BC}=M_B+{r_B\over r_B+r_C}(M_C-M_B).
$$